# Markdown Tables not rendering

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have some table written in markdown, but only the first table that rendered. You can see it on this 
[website](http://docs.paket.id/API/Versi_2.html)

Scroll down and you can find the mistakes. This is my script :

```
Nama Field | Tipe | Diperlukan | Deskripsi
--- | --- | --- | ---

from_name | String | Diperlukan | Nama Pengirim
from_email | String (email address format) | Opsional | Email Penerima, jika kosong maka menggunakan email user yang terdaftar
from_address | String | Diperlukan | Alamat Pengirim 
from_phone | String | Diperlukan | Telefon Pengirim 
from_zip_code | String | Opsional | Kode Pos Pengirim
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well which Markdown renderer are you using? Not all Markdown flavours support tables.

Comment: I'm editing [daux.io](http://daux.io) . I am sure it is support tables, because the first table is render correctly :( @JonSkeet

Comment: So look at the difference between the table that does work and the one that doesn't... I would suggest deleting this question to be honest, as I wouldn't view Markdown as a programming problem as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SOLVED] I shouldn't put new line between `---|---|---` and table content :D

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar problem with one of these generated tables on Github Markdown and I found I needed to put a blank line between my header and my table like this:

```
## Amost always imports

|  R |  Python |    Matlab |
| --------- |:---|:---------|:-----|
| library(tidyverse) |import numpy as np|
```

Without that blank line the table generation did not happen and those same characters appeared in my Github Markdown instead of the desired table.

May's question and answer led me to the solution, even if her issue was actually a different one, so I am dropping this here - it may help someone else. She got my upvote too...

Comment: It doesn't work with me, Am I missing something, can someone have a working demo ?

Answer (score 9):

A minimum of three hyphens are required between the header and the rows before the text can be interpreted as a table.

Comment: this one should certainly be higher up.

Comment: ---Wow............

Answer (score 1):

check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694529/why-are-tables-not-working-in-python-markdown)
I had forgotten to add extensions to the markdown call:

```
markdown.markdown(lines, extensions=['tables'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue, especially when editing **README** files in **GitHub**. It turns out that when one adds paragraph spaces inside a table cell, the table will not likely compile correctly.

What I realized is that whenever you add these paragraph spaces, the table's code structure changes:

###### Table without paragraph spaces:

```
| Col1     |
|----------|
| hi there |
```

###### Table with paragraph spaces:

```
+-------+
| Col1  |
+=======+
| hi    |
|       |
| there |
+-------+
```

I also found that adding these spaces **could change the coding structure of other tables in the file, even if these tables do not have this issue (these paragraph spaces)**.

I don't know why this happens, but the point is that, a least in GitHub, this second kind of table code structure often does not compile correctly. I also don't know if other actions (or *special characters*) imply these changes over the table's code structure. However, given this context, it's important to consider reviewing how one handles other tables in a file or script since the problem could not be in the table one is looking at.