# Why are tables not working in Python-markdown?

Tags: python, markdown

I am trying to render a table into HTML using Markdown syntax with the help of Python-markdown: https://python-markdown.github.io/

I tried the example provided here: https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/tables/

```
from markdown import markdown

s = """
First Header  | Second Header
------------- | -------------
Content Cell  | Content Cell
Content Cell  | Content Cell
"""

html = markdown(s)
print(html)
```

But what I get as the result is:

```
<p>First Header  | Second Header
------------- | -------------
Content Cell  | Content Cell
Content Cell  | Content Cell</p>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since tables is an extension, you need to pass its name to `markdown.markdown`:

`html = markdown(s, extensions=['tables'])`

https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/